# Returning the first possible node's inner text in a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I wrote a method that specificly searches for a given full `xpath` and returns the inner text. But since the files I am working on all have unique node names, I want to do it somehow that only passing the node name do the job.

How my code looks like at the moment:

```
public string FileInfo(string info)
{
    switch (info)
    {
        //FileInfo
        case "fileCreator":
            fileCreator = ztr.SelectSingleNode("//Document/FileInfo/Creator").InnerText;
            return fileCreator;
        case "fileName":
            fileName = ztr.SelectSingleNode("//Document/FileInfo/Name").InnerText;
            return fileName;
      //And so on with lots of other cases!!!
```

How can I make it somehhow that it searches for the first occurance of `info` string that is a xml node so I dont have to be stupid and write all these switch statements...

**UPDATE**

please note **not** all the stuff I want are located in `FileInfo` node...I want the method to search for the node I pass to it! Or better to say I want to pass the name of the node itself into this method and get its value. Sorry if I was confusing prior to this edit!

some more examples in the xml file:

```
/Document/RuntimeInfo/Operator
```

So I want to pass in "Operator" into my method and I get its value! should be up to the method to discover the correct path. the pats are unique so it wouldnt be a bad idea to implement this method.

Comment: update note : could you give an example "out of FileInfo node" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
return ztr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//{0}[contains(name(..),'Info')]", info));
```

If `info` is `Operator` it will return the first `Operator` node that has a parent node with `Info` in its name.

Answer (score 1):

won't this do the job?

`var value = ztr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//{0}", info).InnerText;`

Answer (score 1):

```
return ztr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Document/FileInfo/{0}", 
                            info.Replace("file", "").InnerText;
```

**EDIT**

if the searched node is always at the same nesting level, you could probably use a wild card

```
return ztr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Document/*/{0}", 
                                info).InnerText;
```

By the way, in your example, you pass `fileCreator` to find the `Creator` Node. Typo ?

Comment: hmmm this doesnt work, some stuff that I need to reterive are located in other parent nodes, `Document/FileInfor` is just one of the nodes.

Comment: @Sean87, yeah, I saw your update, can you answer my comment ?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without caring about nesting level?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath:

```
//Document/FileInfo/[0]
```

and your code can be like this:

```
public string FileInfo(string info)
{
    return ztr.SelectSingleNode("//Document/FileInfo/[0]").InnerText;
}
```

See more about xpath [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).